# Bind specific mysql query to session/cookie?

Tags: php, mysql, session

As I'm fairly new to php and mysql I'm not sure how to call this kind of function than I'm trying to figure out.. So I'll try to describe my problem:

Imagine that i have mysql user-table with 5000 users with their account data, each of whom have unique ID.
Then for every ID (user) I have separate data-table, so 5000 tables.

1. User logins to my site, starts session, php user-class is created.
2. Then I ask server to find that user in user-table by email.
3. Ok it scans through user-table and finds data for specific user.
4. Then I ask server to find data-table for that specific user.
5. So as I understand server again searches:

   1. user-table->
   2. finds user with unique-ID->
   3. searches through all 5000 data-tables for matching table->
   4. updates/deletes/etc data in that table.

I imagine that this is would take a lot of time, to search through whole database every time I want to edit one cell for one user..

Is there a way of asking server for specific table for every user session/cookie?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have created a table for each registered user you have a serious design flaw in your database schema. I suggest you write more about it so we can provide some feedback on how it could be changed.

Comment: Why not use a join on the user table to the user detail table?

Comment: @devlincarnate still, having created 5000 tables to add detail data about 5000 users can only be properly fixed by fixing the database schema

Comment: @JimL - I concur that if there is a table for every user, there is a problem.  I was imagining one table with the details for all users, and in that case, a join would eliminate the need to do 2 separate queries.

Comment: @devlincarnate I'm sure that's what the answer will come down to, with the table structures someone could show how they would be properly linked and queried with foreign keys. I was just thinking that at a beginner stage it might be helpful to have your own case fixed/explained as it might be easier to get your head around the data structures you're currently working with I

Comment: This for now is only for learning process. I just made this kind of system(?) for future experiments. I imagine that if every user adds like 10 unique rows per day, that one user/data-table would become huge. It's going to be table with 50 000 row table in one day..

Comment: @JimL & devlincarnate,  I ask in order to learn... could the case not exist where the best option is 1 table per user? If each user were creating their own virtual world in a game for example, or if each user was actually a unique blog page - would that not justify a table?

Comment: Now we're kinda entering the opinionated area of questions, which are generally not accepted here on SO. I can say I have never seen any such cases. Database engines are able to handle tremendous amounts of data, and there is functionality to split huge (millions of rows) tables automagically (sharding)

Comment: One table per user would not scale and defies basic database design principles.  That being said, if you are committed to the poor design, you still could use a join to get the user details table in the same query where you check credentials... well, unless you've thrown all RDBMS principles to the wind and these tables have no relational key.

Comment: Since you're doing this for learning purpose, this is the time to learn proper database design. Variable data should be in table values, not in table or column names.

Comment: Its a horrible idea. So now you want to know what user did some specific action or has a specific permission, or whatever you store in these tables.  You have to run the same query 5000 times changing the tablename each time, instead of being able to run a query on one table. Just an absolute mess. Not to mention now, when you get fired for writing this horrible system, the person hired after you to maintain it will now have to wade through a million user tables to find the main tables of the actual system.

Comment: @developerwjk yeah.. that was my initial question- is it possible not to search through entire database, but use/search in unique table for user that is logged in this system.

Comment: Is it possible? Sure. But it will take way longer than searching one table, even if that one table is extremely huge. You can conquer the performance issue of one huge table with proper keys and indexes. If you have a billion tables that should be just one, you can't conquer that in any way than starting over and redeveloping the system.

Comment: While I agree with the commenters that the question suggests a questionable implementation, a good response should explain in more detail why and suggest a better implementation, namely a small number of tables with proper keys on the user IDs.